# why do I get errors when running this shell script in terminal?

Tags: php, macos, terminal, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to get Doctrine 2 working with Codeigniter 2, and have come across a problem while trying to get Doctrine console up and running, which involves executing a shell script which runs a few lines of php.

I'm using this as a reference:
[Integrating Doctrine 2 with CodeIgniter 2](http://wildlyinaccurate.com/integrating-doctrine-2-with-codeigniter-2/)

I'm new to OSX and new to unix commands but I'm confident I have set up the shell script properly as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
include('doctrine.php');
```

and I have the php file doctrine.php in the same directory.

Whenever I try to run the script with:

```
bash doctrine
```

I get this error:

```
doctrine: line 2: ?php: No such file or directory
doctrine: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `dirname'
doctrine: line 3: `chdir(dirname(__FILE__));'
```

It looks to me like php isn't even running at all. I have the feeling I'm doing something fairly basic wrong!

Any help appreciated,
Mark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a PHP script, not a bash script.

```
php doctrine
```

If you meant for the shebang line to be used then you need to make it executable and run it directly.

```
chmod +x doctrine
./doctrine
```

Comment: ah yes I was also trying to execute it without the ./ - thank you!